# Serial communications with Digilent Atlys board

Tags: terminal, serial-port, fpga, xilinx, spartan

I have an Atlys board http://www.digilentinc.com/Products/Detail.cfm?NavPath=2,400,836&Prod=ATLYS with Spartan6 FPGA on it.

I want to setup serial port communications with host PC via onboard USB-UART bridge by EXAR.
Everything's ok when running Ubuntu with **picocom** terminal on the PC but something goes wrong when trying to setup communications with Putty terminal on Windows machine.

The serial terminal is configured in the next way: speed 9600, data bits: 8, parity: none.

What can be wrong there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have had success with Ubuntu on the same PC, you have shown that the hardware is ok.
With the same settings and a compatible program you should have no problem.

- Have you tried using any other programs (such as HyperTerminal)?
- Have you confirmed that the serial port works in Windows? do you have other devices you could test with?

More detail needed otherwise.

Comment: I think the same (that there is nothing related to hardware). I've also tried connecting with Advanced Serial Terminal (HyperTerm is not installed by default in win7) - result is the same.

Comment: I have also Spartan 3A starter kit board with normal DCE serial port on it, putty works properly with it.

I think the issue is related to XR21V1410 part's (Exar USB-UART bridge) drivers in Windows. I just hope that someone else faced the same problem and solved it.

Comment: Argh! Solved! It was related to usb hub that i'm using with my laptop. Very strange, but some ports are working properly with usb-uart bridge and some don't. And only on Windows